# How to pass args to pods based on Ordinal Index in StatefulSets?

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to pass different args to pods based on their ordinal index in StatefulSets? Didn't find the answer on the StatefulSets documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Recommended way, see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-replicated-stateful-application/#statefulset

```sh
# Generate server-id from pod ordinal index.

[[ `hostname` =~ -([0-9]+)$ ]] || exit 1
ordinal=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}

# ${ordinal} now holds the replica number

server-id=$((100 + $ordinal))

# Copy appropriate conf.d files from config-map to emptyDir.
if [[ $ordinal -eq 0 ]]; then
  # do something
else
  # do something else
fi
```

Comment: Remark for readers: This is in the *official* documentation :) (Thus IMHO it is officially suggested)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a non-hacky way to do it, but I know a hack that works. First, each pod in a StatefulSet gets a unique predictable name. It can discover that name via [the downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/downward-api/) or just by calling `hostname`. So I have shell script as then entrypoint to my container and that script gets it's pod/hostname. From there it calls the "real" executable using command line args appropriate for the specific host.

For example, one of my scripts expects the pod name to be mapped into the environment as `POD_NAME` via downward api. It then does something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

pet_number=${POD_NAME##*-}

if [ pet_number == 0 ]
then
   # stuff here
fi

# etc.
```

Answer (score 3):

I found one less `hacky` way to pass in ordinal index into container using the lifecycle hooks

```
  containers:
  - name: cp-kafka
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:4.0.0
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "2Gi"
        cpu: 0.5
    ports:
    - containerPort: 9093
      name: server
      protocol: TCP
    lifecycle:
      postStart:
        exec:
          command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "export KAFKA_BROKER_ID=${HOSTNAME##*-}"]
    env:
      - name: KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
        value: zk-cs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
      - name: KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
        value: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093
```

Comment: This is still somewhat hacky: According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/#discussion), there is no guarantee, that the postStart hook will be started before the entrypoint. 

"Kubernetes sends the postStart event immediately after the Container is created. There is no guarantee, however, that the postStart handler is called before the Container’s entrypoint is called."

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to track the progress of this, the ticket in question for this feature is here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30427

The proposal involves putting the ordinal as a label on the pod and then using the downward api to pull that out into an environment variable or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid using the Downward API by using `HOSTNAME`:

```
command:
- bash
- c
- |
  ordinal=${HOSTNAME##*-}  
  if [[ "$ordinal" = "0" ]]; then
    ...
  else
    ...
  fi
```