# Map k8s pods 1:1 to VMs in GCE using StatefulSets

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to deploy a set of pods in a k8s cluster that map 1:1 to VMs in an autoscaled instance group in Google Compute Engine, with the IP or hostname of a VM as an argument for the container executable. I've gotten this to work for the most part by using kubectl to create a deployment in the startup script for the VM instances, but when a scale-down event occurs in the instance group, the pod stays running on the k8s cluster and I need a way to destroy it. All that said, the deployment object doesn't feel like the right tool for this use case and I'd really like to use something like StatefulSets.

It looks like I can use the ordinal index in a StatefulSet to customize pod arguments based on the reply to this question: [How to pass args to pods based on Ordinal Index in StatefulSets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731947/how-to-pass-args-to-pods-based-on-ordinal-index-in-statefulsets)

Is there a way this could be done where the StatefulSet replica count automatically scales to the # of VMs in the instance group? It looks like this count shows up in the logs (per https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/viewing-autoscaler-logs), but I don't know how I would construct an API call to reliably adjust the # of replicas and ensure they still map 1:1 to the VMs that are actually running.

Comment: I understand you are talking about Google Cloud Engine when you use the GCE acronym, but please mention the whole name at least once for newcomers and to help with those searching the site for answers.  Thank you for creating a very clear and direct question.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, just made the change. I'm also new to stackoverflow

Comment: Could you provide more information abot your scenario? As you are using Google Compute Engine, you are probably using Kubeadm to manage this cluster. Are you using any [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes-using-node-affinity/) ? How are you scaling and downscaling nodes in kubeadm? Could you provide what you already have to reproduce this scenario?

Comment: This is a GKE cluster, so just using gcloud commands to control nodes in the cluster and kubectl to interact with the k8s API. I should have clarified in the initial post, but the VMs I am trying to map k8s pods to are external to the cluster and scale independently of it. I need a 1:1 mapping of k8s pods to external VMs, but I don't care at all about node affinity (so something like a daemonset would not be what I'm looking for).

Comment: In my current half-working implementation I am distributing the kubeconfig to the external VMs and using sed to modify the deployment manifest to pass the VM's current IP address as an argument. I have the cloud-init script downloading the kubectl binary, then applying the modified manifest.

Comment: So you have `Google Kubernetes Engine` Cluster. Those external VMs are in Google Platform or somewhere else? How you are mapping those VMs? Its something like: 1. You have external VM. 2. Editing deployment to create new deployment (or statefulset as per title) Are you pining somehow thoses VMs from pod?